# Strange Suspend/Resume Failure on HP G61

Tags: 10.10, laptop, suspend, suspend-resume, hp

My HP G61 428CA has an unusual problem. Suspend/resume works fine as long as I don't suspend it for longer than 6 or 8 hours. If I do this, it won't wake up ... the keyboard lights flash reporting what the manual describes as a "BIOS corruption". Does anyone know of any tweaks/quirks that I can use to resolve this problem?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to get an update to your system Bios from the HP website. Click on the **Support Page**, type your make,model number,etc. **Make sure that you get the correct one**, ie. the one for your model. **Otherwise, you could brick your machine!**

Be forewarned, that HP is notorious for removing support for older systems. I had a nightmare trying to find an updated Bios for a friend of mine, and her computer is only 6 years old. **Use reliable sources**.

****If you have a dual Boot system, the simplest method is to boot to Windows, and do the Bios updates from Windows.**** That's is why when switching someone over to Ubuntu I always check for a bios update, before wiping the windows partition (for those that don't want Windows anymore). I guess Windows is useful for something after all! :-)

Here is a link indicating how to do this in Ubuntu. ***Not recommended for beginners...unless you spend sometime doing research and reading and clearly understanding the given procedures.***

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=318789

Comment: Thanks, I've been looking at this for a while. I don't see anything specifically addressing the problems I'm having in any later BIOS revs. It's a pain to do it 'just in case' as I don't run Windows at all, so I'm stuck with the somewhat dangerous Linux method, or perhaps trying to run windows from a USB disk, or even using an alternate internal disk.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced twice the very same failure to resume after an extended period of suspension. HP dv6 3012he, Ubuntu 11.10 Linux kernel 3.0.0-15-generic, AMD64.

Each time I retried repeatedly to start up for a day, then finally took it in to a shop. Each time, the shop techs told me the notebook booted up normally for them. They performed extended diagnostics on the RAM, video card and connections, HD, battery and power adapter/charger and could find nothing wrong.

Ubuntu 11.10 doesn't appear to allow disabling Suspend except by selecting Hibernate or Do Nothing. So I am now careful never to simply close the lid, but to always Shut Down. And never to allow Suspend for more than an hour or so.

At any rate, I have never heard of a corrupted BIOS fixing itself. So I tend to doubt that's what the source of this behavior is.